# Dual or Multiple Callback Design Pattern with JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, callback

I have a callback function that I'd like to execute after 2 separate `$.getScript` calls have successfully loaded.

I'm using the below design, but it feels messy, and the use of a named function feels very un-jQuery

```
var foo_ready = false;
var bar_ready = false;
var dual_callback = function(){
    if(foo_ready && bar_ready)
    {
        //do things
    }
};

 jQuery.getScript('/foo.js', function(){
        foo_ready = true;
        dual_callback();
    });
 jQuery.getScript('/bar.js', function(){
        bar_ready = true;
        dual_callback();
    });
```

Is there a better or more elegant way to do execute a single callback after multiple asynchronous calls have completed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have jQuery 1.5.1 you can do this:

```
$.when( $.getScript('/foo.js'), $.getScript('/bar.js') ).done(function(){ 
     // this is called when both are done.
});
```

Check out the [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: Very cool. +1. I hadn't read about `$.when()` yet; for my particular purposes, I don't have access to 1.5.1; I'm stuck in the doldrums of 1.4.2, for now ;)